# Django and JQuery: Show form when prompted

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

I am currently designing a recipies website, using Django and JQuery. I have the ingredients and recipe instructions stored in the database, with appropriate Django views. Here is an example screenshot:

[image: Example recipe]

I would like to give the user the *option* to edit the ingredients of a recipe. When the user clicks on the "edit" button, I would like to replace the text to it's left, with a form pre-populated with the current ingredient components. Something like this:

[image: Example recipe with first item editing]

What is the best way to add/remove these text input areas? Currently, I am using style elements `display: none` and `display: initial` to get the job done. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think this question is very broad. There are lots of moving parts. For starters, hide the edit button by checking for `{% user.is_authenticated %}` in the template. Next, On button click (edit), via ajax. If you find yourself stuck there, may be you can edit the question, and post a more specific issue you are facing.

Comment: True. I did make it very general. I'll try to pare it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a user is authenticated or not in your views. Set a variable `True` if user is authenticated and `False` if not.

```
# views.py

def my_view(request):
    if user.is_authenticated():
        auth_user = True
    else:
        auth_user = False
    # other code ...
    return render(... {'auth_user': auth_user, ...})
```

Then in your templates, render the form according to the variable `auth_user`.

```
{% if auth_user %}
    Display the form
{% else %}
    Display something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, I've just edited the post narrowing down the question. Unfortunately, your response answers the part of the question I had removed

Comment: I ended up incorporating your answer into what I had been doing.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I found the correct solution, which is a combination of xyres' answer and what I had already been trying to do. Here is some sample code for my final result:

```
<h1>{{ recipe.name }}</h1>

<ul>
    {% for item in recipe.line_items.all %}
        <li>
            <span id="item{{forloop.counter}}_hide">{{ item.full_name }}</span>
            {% if user_auth %}
            <form id="item{{forloop.counter}}_show"
{#                  action="{% url 'line_item:edit' %}"#}
                  class="hide-initial"
                  style="display: inline">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="amount" size="2" value="{{ item.amount }}"/>
                <input type="text" name="unit"   size="4" value="{{ item.unit }}"/>
                <input type="text" name="name"   size="10" value="{{ item.ingredient_adjective }}"/>
                <input type="text" name="name"   size="10" value="{{ item.ingredient_name }}"/>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel"
                       onclick="myFunction('item'+{{forloop.counter}}, true)">
            </form>
            <button id="item{{forloop.counter}}_hide" onclick="myFunction('item'+{{forloop.counter}})">Edit</button>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No ingredients required!</li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if user_auth %}
        <button>Add Ingredient</button>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

This template, accompanied by the following bit of JavaScript will allow the user to toggle the visibility of the form, individually, for each of the different ingredients.

```
$(".hide-initial").css( "display", "none" );

function myFunction(inp, reverse) {
    var show_elements = $("#" + inp + "_show");
    var hide_elements = $("#" + inp + "_hide");
    if(!reverse) {
        show_elements.css("display", "initial");
        hide_elements.css("display", "none");
    } else {
        hide_elements.css("display", "initial");
        show_elements.css("display", "none");
    }
}
```